# functionality between screen and button is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, calculator

I've been trying to debug it but couldn't get anywhere I'm sure problem lies in rendering the value. otherwise it would be something else. I think its the screen component that is making problems or button component. I'm still a beginner in react that's why I cant clearly express where I'm going wrong

```
class Calculator extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    question:"",
    answer: ""
  }
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
  handleClick(e){
    const value = e.target.value;
    switch(value){
      case "=" :{
        if(this.state.question !== ""){
          let result = "";
          try {
            result = eval(this.state.question);
          }
          catch(err){
            this.setState({
              answer: "MATH ERROR"
            });
          }
          if(result ===undefined){
            this.setState({answer: "MATH ERROR"})
          }
          else{
            this.setState({
              question: "",
              answer: result
            });
          }
        }
        break;
    }
      case  "del" : {
        var str = this.state.question;
        str = str.substr(0, str.length-1);
        this.setState({
          question: str
        })
        break;
    }
      case  "AC" : {
    this.setState({
    question: " ",
      answer: " "
  });
        break;
  }
      default:{
        this.setState({
          question: this.state.question += value
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      <div className="main-body">
        <Screen question={this.state.question}/>
        <Screen answer={this.state.answer}/>
        <Buttons handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
class Screen extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
  this.state={
    value: props.value
  }
}
  render(){
    return<div>
      <div className="screen">{this.state.value}</div>
    </div>
  }
}
class Buttons extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      <div className="btn-box">
      <button value="0" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick} >0</button>
      <button value="del" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>DEL</button>
      <button value="AC"className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>AC</button>
      <button value="1" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>1</button>
      <button value="2" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>2</button>
      <button value="3" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>3</button>
      <button value="4" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>4</button>
      <button value="5" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>5</button>
      <button value="6" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>6</button>
      <button value="7" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>7</button>
      <button value="8" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>8</button>
      <button value="9" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>9</button>
      <button value="+" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>+</button>
      <button value="-" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>-</button>
      <button value="=" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>=</button>
      <button value="/" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>/</button>
      <button value="*" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>*</button>
      <button value="." className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>.</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
const container = document.getElementById("calculator");
ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, container);
```

i think functionality between button and screen dosent work in my code. i've been trying to solve it for 2 days couldn't get anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Button component, props.handleClick should be changed to this.props.handleClick.

You're sending **question** and **answer** as the props to the Screen component but you're getting **value**. It's wrong. You should pass value prop or get question and answer props in your Screen component.

And also when your **question** and **answer** get updated, your state in Screen component does not get updated. In order to fix that you should use **[componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)** function.

So this code will fix your issues:

```js
class Calculator extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      question:"",
      answer: ""
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(e){
    const value = e.target.value;
    switch(value){
      case "=" :{
        if(this.state.question !== ""){
          let result = "";
          try {
            result = eval(this.state.question);
          }
          catch(err){
            this.setState({
              answer: "MATH ERROR"
            });
          }
          if(result ===undefined){
            this.setState({answer: "MATH ERROR"})
          }
          else{
            this.setState({
              question: "",
              answer: result
            });
          }
        }
        break;
      }
      case  "del" : {
        var str = this.state.question;
        str = str.substr(0, str.length-1);
        this.setState({
          question: str
        })
        break;
      }
      case  "AC" : {
        this.setState({
          question: " ",
          answer: " "
        });
        break;
      }
      default:{
        this.setState({
          question: this.state.question += value
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      <div className="main-body">
        <Screen question={this.state.question}/>
        <Screen answer={this.state.answer}/>
        <Buttons handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
class Screen extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
    this.state={
      question: props.question,
      answer: props.answer
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(JSON.stringify(prevProps) !== JSON.stringify(this.props)) {
      this.setState({
        question: this.props.question,
        answer: this.props.answer
      });
    }
  }
  render(){
    return<div>
      <div className="screen">{this.state.question || this.state.answer}</div>
    </div>
  }
}
class Buttons extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      <div className="btn-box">
      <button value="0" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick} >0</button>
      <button value="del" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>DEL</button>
      <button value="AC"className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>AC</button>
      <button value="1" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>1</button>
      <button value="2" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>2</button>
      <button value="3" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>3</button>
      <button value="4" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>4</button>
      <button value="5" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>5</button>
      <button value="6" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>6</button>
      <button value="7" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>7</button>
      <button value="8" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>8</button>
      <button value="9" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>9</button>
      <button value="+" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>+</button>
      <button value="-" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>-</button>
      <button value="=" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>=</button>
      <button value="/" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>/</button>
      <button value="*" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>*</button>
      <button value="." className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>.</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
const container = document.getElementById("calculator");
ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />, container);
```

Comment: ok i did what you said ill just add the project link https://codepen.io/ridabatool/pen/QWxgbga?editors=0110

Comment: the whole calculator disappears when i press a button

Comment: @ridzz Sorry, my mistake. I updated my answer. Please check the new one.

Comment: You're welcome. Please pick my answer as the correct answer if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: of course :))))

Answer (score 0):

Add the `this` keyword on each `props`, the component that does not recognize props.

```
<button value="0" className="btn-style" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
  0
</button>;
```

or alternatively

```
render() {
    const { props } = this;
    return (
```

The reason why `screen` does not work. Replace the props value of the Screen component as below.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-body">
          <Screen value={this.state.question} />
          <Screen value={this.state.answer} />
          <Buttons handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And for the Screen component no need for any state, you need to call props as below.

```
class Screen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="screen">{this.props.value}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

whole code.

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      question: '',
      answer: '',
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    switch (value) {
      case '=': {
        if (this.state.question !== '') {
          let result = '';
          try {
            result = eval(this.state.question);
          } catch (err) {
            this.setState({
              answer: 'MATH ERROR',
            });
          }
          if (result === undefined) {
            this.setState({ answer: 'MATH ERROR' });
          } else {
            this.setState({
              question: '',
              answer: result,
            });
          }
        }
        break;
      }
      case 'del': {
        var str = this.state.question;
        str = str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
        this.setState({
          question: str,
        });
        break;
      }
      case 'AC': {
        this.setState({
          question: ' ',
          answer: ' ',
        });
        break;
      }
      default: {
        this.setState({
          question: (this.state.question += value),
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-body">
          <Screen value={this.state.question} />
          <Screen value={this.state.answer} />
          <Buttons handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Screen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="screen">{this.props.value}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Buttons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { props } = this;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="btn-box">
          <button value="0" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            0
          </button>
          <button value="del" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            DEL
          </button>
          <button value="AC" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            AC
          </button>
          <button value="1" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            1
          </button>
          <button value="2" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            2
          </button>
          <button value="3" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            3
          </button>
          <button value="4" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            4
          </button>
          <button value="5" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            5
          </button>
          <button value="6" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            6
          </button>
          <button value="7" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            7
          </button>
          <button value="8" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            8
          </button>
          <button value="9" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            9
          </button>
          <button value="+" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            +
          </button>
          <button value="-" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            -
          </button>
          <button value="=" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            =
          </button>
          <button value="/" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            /
          </button>
          <button value="*" className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            *
          </button>
          <button value="." className="btn-style" onClick={props.handleClick}>
            .
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: adding "this" worked...but value is not rendering on the screen can you help me with that :)

Comment: I'm sorry for this late reply but its still not working. values are not rendering on screen. I'm sorry for disturbing you again and again .

Comment: I have added the whole code, check again, maybe you are making mistake.